# Cannot fetch data in Graphql Relay

Tags: javascript, graphql, apollo-server, relay

I'm learning Relay to use in a React-Relay project. After my research and learning on the internet, I've run into problems with my graphql schema and resolvers. I can't seem to figure out what resolvers do I need and how go about it correctly. If someone can point me in the right direction, that would be great. I have attached my code below. All I'm trying to do is fetch elements of a list using the relay graphql server specification.

Graphql Schema

```
interface Node {
    id: ID!
}

type Link implements Node {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
}

type LinkConnection {
    edges: [LinkEdge]
    pageInfo: PageInfo!
}

type LinkEdge {
    cursor: String!
    node: Link
}

type Query {
    links(after: String, before: String, first: Int, last: Int): LinkConnection
    node(id: ID!): Node
}

type PageInfo {
  hasNextPage: Boolean!
  hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
  startCursor: String
  endCursor: String
}
```

Resolvers

```
const resolvers = {
    Query,
    Node: {
        __resolveType(node, context, info){
            if(node.title){
                return 'Link'
            }
            return null
        }
    },
}
```

Query Resolver

```
const node = async (parent, args, {prisma}) => {
    try{
        console.log('hit')
        const data = await prisma.link.findUnique({
            where: {
                id: Number(args.id)
            }
        })
        console.log(data)
        return data
    } catch(err){
        return err
    }
}

export default {
    node,
}
```

P.S. Im using Apollo Server and Prisma under the hood

Edit:

I solved this issue by realizing that the resolves are invoked in the same order the schema is nested. So by writing separate resolvers for each type and passing the information in parent argument, things worked.